# npm-force-resolutions not working when installing a new package

Tags: node.js, npm, dependencies, npm-install, npm-scripts

I'm using the scripts section of the `package.json` to force resolutions:

```
"preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions"
```

in the resolutions section, I have entered `graceful-fs` with a specified version:

```
"resolutions": {
  "graceful-fs": "^4.2.4",
},
```

When i run `npm i` everything is installed correctly, the set versions are taken in to account. But later on when I install an additional module, e.g. `npm i random-package`, my set versions are being thrown away and I endup with `graceful-fs@1.2.3` and other low versions in some dependencies.

If I clear the node_modules folder and run `npm i` again, everything is alright again.

I also tried setting the resolution more specific, like

```
"resolutions": {
  "glob/**/graceful-fs": "^4.2.4",
},
```

but this doesn't help.

I also tried:

- adding the module as dependency, devDependency or peerDependency
- using a shrinkwrap and overriding it there

but no luck.

what am I missing?

Comment: Hey, any chance you found the solution? I experience the same problem

Comment: I don't think there is no other way around it until you move away from those packages that depend on it or those packages get updated.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I can save  you some time.  What works for me - I don't have to clear node_modules folder after installing the package.  All I have to do is type `npm i`  afterwards and it does the fixes.  Still annoying, but at least you don't have to clear the entire folder first.

Answer (score 21):

The best solution for me to automate this was modifying preinstall script as above:

> "preinstall": "npm install --package-lock-only --ignore-scripts && npx npm-force-resolutions",

Comment: More discussion about this workaround can be found [here](https://github.com/rogeriochaves/npm-force-resolutions/issues/10#issuecomment-676804889).

Answer (score 15):

Best way is to change the `preinstall` script to this:

```
"preinstall": "([ ! -f package-lock.json ] && npm install --package-lock-only --ignore-scripts --no-audit); npx npm-force-resolutions"
```

This will only run `npm install` to create your initial package-lock.json when it does not exist yet.
This is *much faster* than always running both (npm + npx).

As of npm 8.3.0, you can also use npm's [override](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides):

```
{
  "overrides": {
    "graceful-fs": "^4.2.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the best solution that I have found for this.  Thank you.

Comment: I've found that with extreme cases (specifying a `tarball` `version` à la https://stackoverflow.com/a/69591894/132735) the `preinstall` route didn't work and ended up running `npx npm-force-resolutions` manually and `push`ing the changed `lockfile`

Comment: is this a unix-only solution?

Comment: The 'override' isn't, the 'preinstall' script is.

Answer (score 8):

in the resolutions section, you must fix version

```
"resolutions": {
  "graceful-fs": "4.2.4",
},
```

Answer (score 4):

Hi @NthDegree the only way which worked for me was to first run the normal npm install and then add the packages-lock.json file to git. After doing that when you add "preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions",   it always updates the dependency resolution to the version mentioned.

I am not sure if adding packages-lock.json file to git is good or bad but by using this method the CI/CD pipeline works as well.

Comment: Definitely add package-lock.json file to git

Comment: `packages-lock.json` is meant to be in source control. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44210813/1183010  
Furthermore, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68095189/1183010) for a minor tweak to the `preinstall` script solving the 'packages-lock.json` doesn't exist issue.

Answer (score 4):

If all of the above answers don't work and you still get `sh: npm-force-resolutions: command not found`
try the following:

Just change:

`"preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions"`

To:

`"preinstall": "npx force-resolutions"`

> npx force-resolutions does not run when no package-lock.json is detected, and allows the next command inline to be executed as normal

Credit to: https://github.com/rogeriochaves/npm-force-resolutions/issues/10#issuecomment-885458937